# Yosemite Change two destops at once

Tags: macos, display, screen, spaces, mission-control

I'm using two screens on Yosemite 10.10.4. When I change desktops, I have to change manually for first screen and then again for the second.

Is there any way to change both screens at once? Or make "one desktop" for both screens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it seems you wish to  to change the behavior of the **Spaces** feature in Yosemite do this:

- In **System Preferences** select **Mission Control**
- Uncheck **Displays have separate spaces**

This will require a logout to affect the change.

Comment: You are very welcome!